# Blank Screen Issue in Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, interface-builder

I'm working on a game for the iPad, and I have it start up with a menu screen. For a while, the menu screen would come up just fine in the simulator. I'm using the main view controller that xcode provides when starting up a view-based application. But, unfortunately, I accidentally cut off the connection between the UIView and the view controller in interface builder, and after reconnecting it, the screen comes up as blank now. It works fine when I simulate the screen in interface builder, but not when running in xcode. Here's the code for the view controller:

```
//
//  FunctionMachineViewController.h
//  FunctionMachine
//
//  Created by Kameron Schadt on 5/24/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Willamette University. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FunctionMachineViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextField* equation;
IBOutlet UISlider* startLevel;
IBOutlet UITextView* startLevelNumber;

}

- (IBAction) startOnePlayer:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) startTwoPlayer:(id)sender startingEquation:(NSString*)equationUsed;
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider* startLevel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* equation;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* startLevelNumber;

@end


//
//  FunctionMachineViewController.m
//  FunctionMachine
//
//  Created by Kameron Schadt on 5/24/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Willamette University. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FunctionMachineViewController.h"
#import "GameViewController.h"

@implementation FunctionMachineViewController

@synthesize equation, startLevel, startLevelNumber;

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender {
[startLevelNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]]];
}

-(IBAction)startOnePlayer:(id)sender
{
GameViewController* GameView = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[GameView isOnePlayer:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:GameView animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)startTwoPlayer:(id)sender startingEquation:(NSString*)equationUsed
{
GameViewController* GameView = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[GameView isOnePlayer:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:GameView animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I didn't really see any problem here, so I'm assuming it has something to do with me reconnecting the view controller to the view. I don't have an actual view file that I'm using, just the viewcontroller. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the setting of "Main nib file base name" in [YourApp]-info.plist, in the "Supporting Files" folder – if you've changed the name of your root view controller, you may need to change the name here as well.

Comment: Okay, I checked that spot, and the main nib file base name is MainWindow. I haven't messed with the window, just the view for the view controller. Trying to change the file base name just makes it crash.

Comment: I made an exact copy of the project and tried it again, and now it works fine. It was probably something in the info file like you said. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason my Referencing outlet for the App Delegate was disconnected.

Try creating a referencing outlet from delegate to File's Owner using the connections inspector (farthest right menu) for your App Delegate.